# Dynamic Query for Retriving the translated column value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `table_lookup`. This is the master table which has all the lookup codes  like

```
LOOKUP_TYPE       LOOKUP_CODE   MEANING                             ENABLED_FLAG

EMP_CAT           3             Hourly with fixed hours per week    Y
EMP_CAT           4             Hourly                              Y
EMP_CAT           CAS           Casual                              Y
EMP_CAT           FR            Full-time regular                   Y
EMP_CAT           FR_01         Full-time                           Y
ABSENCE_CATEGORY  DLHM          Leave                               Y
ABSENCE_CATEGORY  DLHNM         Leave on the death of a husband     Y
ABSENCE_CATEGORY  DLR           Leave on the death of a relative    Y
ABSENCE_CATEGORY  GB_ADO        Adoption                            Y
ABSENCE_CATEGORY  GB_PAT_ADO    Paternity adoption                  Y
NATIONALITY       PY            Paraguayan                          Y
NATIONALITY       QA            Qatari                              Y
NATIONALITY       RO            Romanian                            Y
NATIONALITY       RS            Serbian
```

This table is referenced in different tables like 
`table_assignment`

```
emp no.    name                   Employee category              active/inactive

1          divya                  3                                A
2          abc                    FR                               A
3          XYZ                    4                                I
4          aMY                    100                              A
```

Table `table_nationality`

```
Emp no.        nationality               

1              QA
2              RS
4              RO
```

That is the `lookup_code` f is translated in the `table_Assignment` `employee_category` column and nationality column in `table_nationality`.

I have a query like:

```
select emp_no.,
       name,
       employee_category
  from table_assignment lookup_assignmen,
       table_lookup lookup_stg
 where lookup_stg.lookup_type = 'EMP_CAT'
   AND LOOKUP_STG.LOOKUP_CODE = lookup_assignmen.employee_category;
```

SIMILARLY for `table_nationality` something like:

```
select emp_no.,
       nationality    
  from TABLE_NATIONALITY lookup_NATIONALITY,
       table_lookup lookup_stg
 where lookup_stg.lookup_type = 'NATIONALITY'
   AND LOOKUP_STG.LOOKUP_CODE = lookup_NATIONALITY.employee_category;
```

Now I want a dynamic query which detects if in say for example `table_assignment` there is any employee category which is not there in the `table_lookup`.

For example : In the `table_assignment` there is a value 100 given in the employee category column this is not there in the `table_lookup`. 
Such values should be retrieved in a query but the query should be dynamic such that it should retrieve all the invalid lookup values in `table_Assignment`, `table_nationality` or any other
tables. I can input the `lookup_type` and table name in the query and the invalid values should be retrieved.

How do I change my static query to dynamic?

Comment: Why do you want it to be dynamic? Do you have an unknown number of 'child tables'? How do you know the relevant column name in the child table? And do the child tables have foreign key constraints to the lookup table - I guess not from this design. (Er, and that you're worried about orphan data...) Why have you got everything in a single look-up table instead of one per type which would allow proper referential integrity?

Comment: @Alex Poole That is how lookup codes are present in HCM (Oracle HCM)

Comment: Dynamic SQL in SQL can be tricky and should be avoided if possible.  Would a one-time PL/SQL function be good enough?  Or do you want a framework for building similar dynamic queries?

Comment: @JonHeller -I have a function already.. I am required to create a dynamic SQL only. Framework would be of great help

Answer (score 2):

you can union all the invalid codes and avoid dynamic sql.

```
select *
from (
  select emp_no as entity_id, 'emp_cat' as lookup_type, eployee_category as invalid_lookup_code
  from table_assignment e
  left join table_lookup r
  on e.employee_category = r.lookup_code
  and r.lookup_type = 'emp_cat'
  where r.lookup_type is null
  union all
  select emp_no as entity_id, 'nationality' as lookup_type, nationality as invalid_lookup_code
  from table_nationality e
  left join table_lookup r
  on e.employee_category = r.lookup_code
  and r.lookup_type = 'nationality'
  where r.lookup_type is null
) as t
where t.lookup_type = 'nationality'
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it.  Unless there's some unusual situation like there are hundreds of tables or they change frequently.

Comment: @JonHeller- They can change frequently plus yes there are more than 100 of tables... and we just wan tto check the inavlid lookup codes .. whatsoeevr the values be

Answer (score 1):

You can run dynamic SQL inside SQL with a package that combines Oracle Data Cartridge with the ANY types.  The code below uses [my open source version](https://github.com/jonheller1/method4) of this idea.

Even using pre-built PL/SQL, this will still be a difficult task since building queries in queries is confusing.  And it's not clear how the tables are mapped together, it looks like there are no foreign keys or standard names.  I assume there's a mapping table somewhere, or one can be created.  For the demo, I created this:

```
create table lookup_map(
    table_name varchar2(30),
    column_name varchar2(30),
    lookup_type varchar2(100)
);
insert into lookup_map
select 'TABLE_ASSIGNMENT', 'EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY', 'EMP_CAT' from dual union all
select 'TABLE_NATIONALITY', 'NATIONALITY', 'NATIONALITY' from dual;
commit;
```

This code will build and run dynamic queries for each table, and will `UNION ALL` the results.

```
select * from table(method4.dynamic_query(
    q'[
        select replace(replace(replace(q'!
                select '#TABLE_NAME#' table_name, emp_no, #COLUMN_NAME#
                from #TABLE_NAME#
                left join table_lookup
                    on #TABLE_NAME#.#COLUMN_NAME# = table_lookup.lookup_code
                    and table_lookup.lookup_type = '#LOOKUP_TYPE#'
                where table_lookup.lookup_code is null
            !',
            '#TABLE_NAME#', table_name),
            '#COLUMN_NAME#', column_name),
            '#LOOKUP_TYPE#', lookup_type) v_sql
        from lookup_map
    ]'
));

TABLE_NAME         EMP_NO   EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY
----------         ------   -----------------
TABLE_ASSIGNMENT   4        100
```

To avoid quotation-mark-hell it's best to use the alternative quoting mechanism (q') and REPLACE.  The quotation marks look unmatched in the Stackoverflow syntax highlighter but it should look better in an Oracle IDE.

This is overkill for this exact query.  But it gives you plenty of room to grow.  You can change the queries and make them even more dynamic without any additional PL/SQL code.

Comment: Will definately try this out and let you know

Comment: ORA-00904: "METHOD4"."DYNAMIC_QUERY": invalid identifier this error is coming

Comment: What exactly is #table name# ? as in what is "#"

Comment: @divya.trehan573 - did you follow the link at the start of the answer? You need to install Jon's method4 application - the ORA-00904 means you haven't done that. The `#TABLE_NAME#` etc. are placeholders in the code; the `replace()` calls put the actual value in from the `lookup_map` table in when it is executed.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have access to sql dev not sql plus

Comment: @divya.trehan573 - to run Jon's scripts? You can do that from SQL Developer; unzip them to the directory you have configured inTools->Datebase->Worksheet->Select default path to look for scripts, then start/@ will find them there.