# Query to find invalid rows dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table_lookup. This is the master table which has all the lookup codes like

```
LOOKUP_TYPE       LOOKUP_CODE   MEANING                             ENABLED_FLAG

EMP_CAT           3             Hourly with fixed hours per week    Y
EMP_CAT           4             Hourly                              Y
EMP_CAT           CAS           Casual                              Y
EMP_CAT           FR            Full-time regular                   Y
EMP_CAT           FR_01         Full-time                           Y
ABSENCE_CATEGORY  DLHM          Leave                               Y
ABSENCE_CATEGORY  DLHNM         Leave on the death of a husband     Y
ABSENCE_CATEGORY  DLR           Leave on the death of a relative    Y
ABSENCE_CATEGORY  GB_ADO        Adoption                            Y
ABSENCE_CATEGORY  GB_PAT_ADO    Paternity adoption                  Y
NATIONALITY       PY            Paraguayan                          Y
NATIONALITY       QA            Qatari                              Y
NATIONALITY       RO            Romanian                            Y
NATIONALITY       RS            Serbian
```

This table is referenced in different tables like **table_assignment**

```
emp no.    name                   Employee category              active/inactive

1          divya                  3                                A
2          abc                    FR                               A
3          XYZ                    4                                I
4          aMY                    100                              A
```

Table **table_nationality**

```
Emp no.        nationality               

1              QA
2              RS
4              RO
```

That is the lookup_code f is translated in the table_Assignment employee_category column and nationality column in table_nationality.

I have a query like:

```
select emp_no.,
       name,
       employee_category
  from table_assignment lookup_assignmen,
       table_lookup lookup_stg
 where lookup_stg.lookup_type = 'EMP_CAT'
   AND LOOKUP_STG.LOOKUP_CODE = lookup_assignmen.employee_category;
```

SIMILARLY for table_nationality something like:

```
select emp_no.,
       nationality    
  from TABLE_NATIONALITY lookup_NATIONALITY,
       table_lookup lookup_stg
 where lookup_stg.lookup_type = 'NATIONALITY'
   AND LOOKUP_STG.LOOKUP_CODE = lookup_NATIONALITY.employee_category;
```

Now I want a dynamic query/package which detects if in say for example table_assignment there is any employee category which is not there in the table_lookup. i.e. **gives the row where the lookup is invalid**

For example : In the table_assignment there is a value 100 given in the employee category column this is not there in the table_lookup. Such values should be retrieved in a query but the query should be dynamic such that it should retrieve all the invalid lookup values in table_Assignment, table_nationality or any other tables. I can input the lookup_type and table name in the query and the invalid values should be retrieved.

I have created a packege for the same but its not working if i pass the p_tablename,column in the column. How can i modify this package

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE body XXHCM_LOOKUP_VALIDATION
AS
PROCEDURE XX_VALIDATION_LOOKUP(
    ERRBUF OUT VARCHAR2,
    RETCODE OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_TABLE_NAME  VARCHAR2,
    P_LOOKUP_TYPE varchar2,
    p_column varchar2)
as
begin

select XXHCM_LOOKUP_EXT.*
from XXHCM_LOOKUP_EXT LOOKUP_STG,
P_TABLE_NAME table_STG
where table_STG.P_LOOKUP_TYPE<>LOOKUP_STG.LOOKUP_CODE
and LOOKUP_STG.LOOKUP_TYPE=P_LOOKUP_TYPE;

dbms_output.put_line('hdhd');
end; 
end;
```

Comment: How is this substantially different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35576980/266304)?

Answer (score 1):

The feature you require is "[dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm)". You need to generate one SQL statement as a variable for each table you want to inspect, and then execute that variable. It's a bit of a mind-bend, but caters for this sort of example.